# Match word with Regex (at the beginning, the end or in the middle) of text

Tags: regex

I always wondered if it was possible using one single Regex pattern to find a word in a string wherever it is located.

Let's say I want to find a word of 6 letters starting with a capital 'B' and ending with a lower 'r', for this sake let's use the word 'Butter'.

I want it to match within these sentences:

```
"Butter is good"
"I love Butter"
"Where my Butter is?"
```

But I also DON'T want a match for these:

```
"zzzButter is good"
"I love zzzButter"
```

Using a simple pattern like this: `"/(B[a-z]{4}r)/i"` isn't enough...

Any idea if it is possible to get this done in ONE single Regex?

Comment: use a word boundary `\b`

Comment: can you show me how using my example ?

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with word boundaries on each side:

```
/\bB[a-z]{4}r\b/i
```

Comment: Terrific! Is it possible to use it to match 2 words at a time too ? Like "\bB[a-zA-Z]{4}r[\ ]+Beer\b" ?

Comment: Yes sure you can use: `/\b(Beer|B[a-z]{4}r)\b/i`

Answer (score 3):

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hA4hE7/1)

Try this regex, you can use /g for multiple words in the same sentence

```
/\bB\w{4}r\b/g
```